# Context.Consumer vs useContext() to access values passed by Context.Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
    {value => { }}
</MyContext.Consumer>

VS

let value = useContext(MyContext);
```

What is the difference between this two snippets, using Context.Consumer and using useContext hook to access values passed by the context Provider? I think useContext will subscribe to the context Provider, since we passed the Context as an argument, so that it will trigger a re-render, when the provider value changes.

Comment: Isn't first one is for Class component and 2nd one is for functional component ?

Comment: Is there any way we can skip both and have context value directly? I mean get it from createContext

Answer (score 65, accepted):

That is correct. They will do basically the same thing.

In my opinion, the `useContext` hook has a much nicer and readable syntax.

**From React Docs:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

> **useContext**

> const value = useContext(MyContext);
> Accepts a context object (the value returned from React.createContext) and returns the current context value for that context. The current context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the calling component in the tree.

> **When the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the component updates, this Hook will trigger a rerender with the latest context value passed to that MyContext provider.**

**Also from React Docs:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

> **Context.Consumer**

> ```
> <MyContext.Consumer>
>  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
> </MyContext.Consumer>
> ```

> A React component that subscribes to context changes. This lets you subscribe to a context within a function component.

**UPDATE:**

<s>**From:** http://brianyang.com/react-hooks-a-deeper-dive-featuring-usecontext-and-usereducer/</s>

**From:** https://testdriven.io/blog/react-hooks-advanced/

> The new `useContext` hook to consume context **does not change the concepts surrounding context,** hence the plunge above. This context hook only gives us an extra, much prettier, way to consume context. It's amazingly helpful when applying it to components consuming multiple contexts.

Comment: Thanks. So if both subscribes to the context, what is the basic difference? Not regarding syntax.

Comment: This article might help: I'll add it to the answer. http://brianyang.com/react-hooks-a-deeper-dive-featuring-usecontext-and-usereducer/

Comment: @Bastiat Isn't first one is for Class component and 2nd one is for functional component ?

Comment: @vikramvi yes and no, you need to use Context.consumer with class components because you cannot use a hook inside a class component. However, the consumer simply passes values to the function, as you see in the example above, but the Consumer component doesnt know or care what is returned from that function. it could return class or functional components. In the end, it's just handing out values. As mentioned though, Hooks tend to me much cleaner especially if you have multiple providers.

Comment: @Bastiat ` it will only rerender when those selected items change. `.  Component always re-rendered even if we use `Context.Consumer`, please check https://codesandbox.io/s/lpk7xrwnmm?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: @Bastiat – That is wrong. Both `useContext` and `Context.Consumer` will trigger a re-render when any item in the context is changed.

Comment: The last link is broken. Correct link: https://testdriven.io/blog/react-hooks-advanced/ (which is also the *original* source of that article, see [WBM](https://web.archive.org/web/20210524090318/https://brianyang.com/react-hooks-a-deeper-dive-featuring-usecontext-and-usereducer/)).

Comment: @FabianIwand thanks! I've updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to think of the difference between the two based on the usecases.
If I have a <Context.Provider> as a parent element within another component but I need to use a value within the Context towards the child element, then I would not be able to get the scope of useContext hook right there. Because the component we are in is not within Provider so obviously we need to create a <Context.Consumer> as the child element's wrapper and get the context value.

```
const CurrentComponent = () => {
     const { contextValue } = useContext("CreatedContext"); // We cannot use this
     return (
           <ParentElement>
             <Context.Provider>
                <ChildElement>
                   <Context.Consumer>
                      {({contextValue}) => {
                         <InnerElement prop={contextValue}/>
                      }}
                   </Context.Consumer>
                </ChildElement>
             </Context.Provider>
           </ParentElement>
     )
}
```